# Google Cloud Logging API - Missing authentication(user) information from audit logs for certain log entries

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

Google Cloud Logging API currently provides audit logs for App Engine, BigQuery, and Cloud Dataflow. According to Google docs, authentication information [field](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/api/ref/rest/Shared.Types/AuditLog#AuthenticationInfo) of an Audit Log [entry](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/api/ref/rest/Shared.Types/AuditLog#SCHEMA_REPRESENTATION) contains email address of the user that performed the actual operation. But this field is empty for certain log entries of type app engine and bigquery. Is there a documentation that gives the list of activities which doesn't provide the authentcationInfo in the API response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For App Engine, identity information is not captured for logs coming from the legacy App Engine API.

For BigQuery, identity information is currently redacted from the logs unless:

1. the user is a service account
2. the user is a member of the authorized domain associated with the project
3. the user has permission to run queries in the project and the action is either administrative or job.insert

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/) have been updated to reflect this.